# Function to Class Based View JSON Type of Request Django

Tags: python, django, json

I have a translation engine api made using Django Python and it has a function that I want to be made into a class based view:

```
def i18n_newkey(rin):
    request = Request(rin, JSONParser())

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(rin.body)
        .... # Parsing and other code here and finally,
        return JSONResponse(kdata)
```

Where the JSONResponse is an HttpResponse that renders it's content into JSON.

My url: `url(r'^savekey', 'i18n_newkey'),`

I'm new to django and I wanted to convert my function based view to class view, I've read the Django Documentation but I cannot seemed to dig it in this particular code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [JsonRequestResponseMixin](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/other.html#jsonrequestresponsemixin) will do exactly what you want.